# When is $\int_1^\infty \frac{x+\sqrt{x+\ln(x+2)}}{(x^a+\cos x)^{1/3}}\,\mathrm{d}x$ finite?

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

How do I solve the following problem?

> For which of the following values of $a$ is the integral
>   $$
>  \int_1^\infty \frac{x+\sqrt{x+\ln(x+2)}}{(x^a+\cos x)^{1/3}}\,\mathrm dx
> $$
>   finite?
>   $$
>  a < 9/2, \quad
>  a > 6, \quad
>  a > 9/2, \quad
>  a < 6.
> $$

Comment: what do you mean with over?

Comment: limited(not infinity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say $a>6$. The numerator
$$
x+\sqrt{x+\ln(x+2)}\sim x\qquad\mbox{ as }x\to +\infty
$$
while the denominator
$$
(x^a+\cos x)^{1/3}\sim x^{a/3}\qquad\mbox{ as }x\to +\infty\ .
$$
Hence the ratio 
$$
\frac{x+\sqrt{x+\ln(x+2)}}{(x^a+\cos x)^{1/3}}\sim \frac{1}{x^{a/3-1}}\ .
$$
To ensure convergence at infinity, we need to impose
$$
a/3-1 >1\Rightarrow a>6\ .
$$

Comment: ti ringrazio :)